# how to check if a word is in a phrase in python (simple search engine)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay I've been having some problems with my code, it's a simple python search engine whereby the user inputs a sentence and a word. If the word is in the sentence then the code is to output "word found" and if the word is not found then it is supposed to print "word not found".

Here is my code:

```
text = input()
word = input()

def wrong(text, word):
    print("Word not found")    
wrong(text, word)

def right(text, word):
    print("Word found")
right(text, word)

def check(right, wrong):
    if text.index == word:
        return right
    elif text.index != word:
        return wrong
check(right, wrong)
```

So instead what I've been getting as output is both the responses instead of just one. Please help me.

Comment: `if word in text: ... else: ...`

Comment: You're calling `wrong` and `right` right after you defined them, unconditionally… So yes, both will always print.

Comment: [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) is a function that you must call, not something that you compare a string to.

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for something like? :

```
a = 'some word'
b = 'some'

if b in a:
  print('yes')
else:
  print('no')
```

Comment: I am yes, I didn't try that yet let me see

Comment: yes it is fully functional. Thank you

Comment: Please do not forget to mark this as the correct answer if it is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input('input text: ')
word = input('input a word: ')

if word in text:
    print('Word found!')
else:
    print('Word not found')
```